# how can i clean correctly struct containing vector c++?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'am beginner in c++. i meet a problem to clean struct containing vector;

this is my struct:

```
namespace std {

struct EvalItem {
    unsigned int _c; // client
    unsigned int _t; // tour
    unsigned int _p; // position
    unsigned int _dem;
    vector<unsigned int> _deltatScenario; // difference in travel length

    EvalItem(const unsigned int & c, const unsigned int & t, const unsigned int & p,
                 const unsigned int & dem)
                 :_c(c), _t(t), _p(p),_dem(dem){};


};
```

Now, in some function i use this struct; like that:

```
void function1()
{
  vector<EvalItem> best;
   ......
   .....
   ......
while(client.size()>0
{
............
...........

    if(best.size()==0)
     {
        best.clear();
      best.push_back(eval);

    }else if(this->_problem->better(eval._deltatScenario,best[0]._deltatScenario)){

        best.clear();
        best.push_back(eval);
    }else if(eval._deltatScenario==best[0]._deltatScenario){
      best.push_back(eval);

        }
    }
}
 }
```

in the first iteration of "while" it work and i have my *best* with correcte value but in the second iteration and if the programme ***clean*** my struct to put the new value, this don't work and i have an empty *best*.

i put images to explain more this situation:

first iteration: 
i have the good values for my best

[image]

but in second iteration and when the programme clean my best to put the new values, i have empty line in best like this: 
[image]

i dont know what is the problem, can you help me please??!!

Comment: Please don't add user-code in the std-namespace

Comment: thank's for your remark, but why?

Comment: @Mouaici_Med because it makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: @Mouaici_Med You're using the debugger, but why are you not single stepping through your program, watching variables, examining the flow of your program, etc?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, i do it,, but i don't know why when i clean "best" to put new values, i have this problem, all variables work correctely, but "best " when i clean it to put new value, i have problem

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  All you're showing us is a declaration of a local vector `best`, and then testing if it's empty (which it is).   In other words, none of that code even gets executed beyond `if (best.size() == 0) { }`.  Those `.........` you place in your code hides what you're really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't put your code in `namespace std`, that may lead to bad consequences.

Second, dont start names with single underscore, it might be a macro, and you won't even know what's happening.

About `std::vector`: Vector allocates memory exponentialy, one implementation might be that it allocates double the memory it had allocated before allocation (like 1,2,4,8,16...). If you - at some point - have for example 1000 elements in your vector, and then clear it, the allocated memory is still there, for example space is still allocated for 1024 objects after `clear()`. If you want to deallocate that memory, you might call `shrink_to_fit`, or assign a new, empty vector to existing one:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //0

for(size_t i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    vec.push_back(0);
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //1024

vec.clear();
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //1024

vec.shrink_to_fit();
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //0

for(size_t i=0; i<2000; ++i)
    vec.push_back(0);
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //2048

vec = std::vector<int>();
std::cout << vec.capacity() << std::endl; //0
```

Comment: thank you for your response but i dont find the fucntion shrink_to_fit();

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is c++11